# autoformat Time in TextBox ASP.Net Javascript

Tags: javascript, time

I need to format time like 10:00 PM or 12:23 AM in both 12 or 24 hour format using Javascript

Answer (score 0):

10 way to do it

http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/formatting_time_using_javascript.php3

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

var a_p = "";
var d = new Date();

var curr_hour = d.getHours();

if (curr_hour < 12)
   {
   a_p = "AM";
   }
else
   {
   a_p = "PM";
   }
if (curr_hour == 0)
   {
   curr_hour = 12;
   }
if (curr_hour > 12)
   {
   curr_hour = curr_hour - 12;
   }

var curr_min = d.getMinutes();

document.write(curr_hour + " : " + curr_min + " " + a_p);

//-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some stuff from [depressedpress.com](http://www.depressedpress.com/Content/Development/JavaScript/Extensions/DP_DateExtensions/Index.cfm). Hope this helps you!

Also, [javascripttoolbox's](http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/lib/date/) date lib can also do few tricks with date-times.